# .htaccess mod rewrite 301-redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want:
all links which not contained filename (not .html, .jpg, .png, .css) redirect with state 301 to directory, for example: http://mysite.com/article -> http://mysite.com/article/
But http://mysite.com/article/article-15.html not redirects.
What regulat expression I must write to .htaccess for adding slash to virtual directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following might work:

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

When it comes to mod_rewrite I can never be sure without testing though...

Answer (score 1):

Clarification needed:

Given the url:
http://server/path/file

Does that get redirected to:
http://server/path/

Or does it get redirected to:
http://server/path/file/

As in: Do you want the redirects to go to the parent path, or do you just want to add a slash and assume directory out of the current path?

Answer (score 0):

MB's RewriteRule above will fail on paths like `/a` because it needs to match at least two characters after the slash. Moreover it only matches on top directory URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^(([^\/]+\/)*[^\/\.]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Is the purpose of this to reduce history pollution/false negatives?