# Remove trailing Slash Redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a 301 mod rewrite rule that will redirect the following example URL

http://www.example.com/people/john-doe/

to

http://www.example.com/people/john-doe (no slash)

It will only apply to URLS in the people directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess mod rewrite 301-redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81631/htaccess-mod-rewrite-301-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^people/(.*)/$ /people/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/people/(.*)/$ /people/$1
```